# C++ constructing global variable

Tags: c++, memory, scope, global-variables

i have a c++ code:

```
// includes, variables etc...
GraphStructure graphStructure;

void getInput() {
    graphStructure = GraphStructure(nodesCount, edgesCount);
    // HERE, the destructor is called!
    graphStructure.init(nodesCount, edgesCount);
    // Same code as constructor, but now its okay.
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    getInput();
}
```

I would like to know, why the destructor of the object is called directly after its construction. Destructors are called after end of scope of a variable, which should be after the main function end.

Comment: you know...c++ doesn't have GC, so it won't call the destructor unless you tell it to

Comment: @Steve : not necessarily true. If you create a class type object on the stack the destructor will be called when it goes out of scope or when the compiler feels there are no side effects and can dispose of it before going out of scope. The latter is what I think happened here.

Comment: You have to obey the rule of three (or five) here - write a proper assignment operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GraphStructure(nodesCount, edgesCount)` is a *temporary instance* of `GraphStructure`. As such, its destructor is called when the full expression in which it is contained is evaluated (the end being at the semicolon `;`).

If it were a local instance it would be bound by the scope of *`getInput()`*, not `main()`. Its destructor would get called when the compiler has reached the end of `getInput()` (just before the ending brace `}`). And the destructors of any local variables in main would get called when main finishes execution.